# My code is not printing the correct values

Tags: python

I have a code that runs through data.csv file, and it prints out values. But the values do not fit the test cases.

import csv
    filePath="data.csv"
    with open(filePath) as csvfile:
        reader=csv.DictReader(csvfile)

```
    print("========================================================")
    print("Display item stock level above certain amount")
    print("========================================================")
    amount = input("Enter amount : ")
    print("========================================================")

    for row in reader:
        if (row['STOCK LEVEL'] >= amount):
            print("PRODUCT ID : {0}\nNAME : {1}\nLEVEL : {2}".format(row['PRODUCT ID'],row['NAME'],row['STOCK LEVEL']))
            print()
```

My codes asks an int input from the user, and would read through the file and print the details of the item, eg Product ID, name, stock level.

but when i enter 8, it should print the details for stock level above 8 and 12, but it only prints the details for 8. When i ask for 12, it would print the details for every item, (5, 7, 8, 12), which is wrong.

Comment: You need to convert it to an integer, so `amount = int(input(...))`. You should do the same for `row['STOCK LEVEL']`. Right now you compare the items *lexicographically*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible error could be that you are comparing an integer value with a string value in line 8 (inside if condition)

The output of 'amount' in line 5 will have the type 'string', which cannot be compared with any numerical value.

I suggest you convert it into 'int'

```
amount = int(input("bla bla"))
```

I'm hoping your output of `row["Stock level"]` is an integer too. If it's not, put it inside int() function too.

So, your final code will be:

```
int(row["Stock level"]) >= amount
```

Now try. Hope it helps. If this doesn't work, tell me.

Comment: `row['STOCK LEVEL']` is not a numerical value either.

Comment: I've already updated my solution. And thank you very much to point it out @Willem Van Onsem

Comment: @ParthikB. Thank for the help! I realised from your explanation the type retrieved from the excel has to be the same as the one i am comparing. I only checked the right side but never the left side.

Comment: Happy to help!!